# Golang on App Engine Datastore - Using PutMulti to Improve Performance

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a GAE Golang app that should be able to handle hundreds of concurrent requests, and for each requests, I do some work on the input and then store it in the datastore.

Using the task queue (appengine/delay lib) I am getting pretty good performance, but it still seems very  inefficient to perform single-row inserts for each request (even though the inserts are deferred using task queue).

If this was not app engine, I would probably append the output a file, and every once in a while I would batch load the file into the DB using a cron job / some other kind of scheduled service.

So my questions are:

1. Is there an equivalent scheme I can implement on app engine? I was
   thinking - perhaps I should write some of the rows to memecache, and
   then every couple of seconds I will bulk load all of the rows from
   there and purge the cache.
2. Is this really needed? Can the datastore
       handle thousands of concurrent writes - a write per http request my
       app is getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends really on your setup. Are you using ancestor queries? If so then your are limited to 1 write per second PER ancestor (and all children, grand children). The datastore has a natural queue so if you try and write too quickly it will queue it. It only becomes an issue if you are writing too many way too quickly. You can read some best practices [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention).

If you think you will be going over that limit use a [pull queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull) with [async multi puts](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/async). You would put each entity in the queue. With a backed module (10 minute timeouts) you can pull in the entries in batches (10-50-100...) and do a put_async on them in batches. It will handle putting them in at the proper speed. While its working you can queue up the next batch. Just be wary of the timeout.